# angular js get refresh token

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What i want to do is this:

if im getting 401 response i want to intercept and send another post request to get new token from my server. but i cant do it in the angular interceptor. i get this error:

Circular dependency found: authService <- authIn <- $http <- $translateStaticFilesLoader

whats the problem, and how i can do what i want?

```
  return {
        'responseError': function(rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 401) {
                authService.getNewToken();
                return $q.reject(rejection);
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Obviously, you have a circular dependency.

Comment: OK, but how i can do such thing?

Comment: you can use this https://gist.github.com/Mirodil/952e5932c284a2d205db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `$injector` and make something like this:

```
$provide.factory('MyHttpInterceptor', ['$q', '$injector', function ($q, $injector) {
  return {
    responseError: function (rejection) {
      console.log("MyHttpInterceptor rejection ", rejection); // Contains the data from the first response.
      var $http = $injector.get('$http');
      // Return another $http call.
      return $http.get('http://ip.jsontest.com/');
    }
  };
}]);
```

The bad side of such solution is that you can get into infinite loop of $http calls. If your second $http request fails again and again you will always fire Interceptor. You should at least add check for status code like you have made it `rejection.status === 401`.

The working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VAOjR1IGfIn5H7EsQGVx?p=preview) with super simple example.

Also you may look at this module https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth.